# WP Bootstrap Navwalker collapse not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to make the collapse work on my menu using WP Bootstrap Navwalker.

Below is my code :

```
<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
       wp_nav_menu( array(
           'menu'              => 'primary',
           'theme_location'    => 'primary',
           'depth'             => 2,
           'container'         => 'div',
           'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
           'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
           'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
           'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
           'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
       );
      ?>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

And below is what I defined in my functions.php :

```
require_once('WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker.php');

function wpb_theme_setup(){
// Nav Menus
register_nav_menus(array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' )
));
}
```

And my bootstrap.min.js :

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Can anybody point out where I got it wrong? Thank you so much in advance!

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue when I changed WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker ()) and WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker.php to all lower case letters.